# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table_name . '` '
            . '(`day`, `campaign_name`, `campaign_id`, `views`, `CPM`, `cost`, `currency`, `cost_EUR`) VALUES '
            . '(:day, :campaign_name, :campaign_id, :views, :CPM, :cost, :currency, :cost_EUR)';

$this->_dbi->execute($sql, array(
            ':day'        => $day,
            ':campaign_name'      => $campaignName,
            ':campaign_id'    => $campaignID,
            ':views'          => $views,
            ':CPM'        => $cpm,
            ':cost'     => $cost_EUR,
            ':currency'       => 'EUR',
            ':cost_EUR' => $cost_EUR
));
```

As far as I can tell the number of variables do match the number of tokens.
I just can't figure out the error here.

Comment: Looks ok. Are you sure the error is referring to that exact query?

Comment: execute( array( ':name' => 'Apple', ':colour' => 'red' ) ); execute have only one perameter

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pass an array to the execute method.  So your updated code would look like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table_name . '` '
            . '(`day`, `campaign_name`, `campaign_id`, `views`, `CPM`, `cost`, `currency`, `cost_EUR`) VALUES '
            . '(:day, :campaign_name, :campaign_id, :views, :CPM, :cost, :currency, :cost_EUR)';
$sth = $this->_dbi->prepare($sql);    
$sth->execute(array(
            ':day'        => $day,
            ':campaign_name'      => $campaignName,
            ':campaign_id'    => $campaignID,
            ':views'          => $views,
            ':CPM'        => $cpm,
            ':cost'     => $cost_EUR,
            ':currency'       => 'EUR',
            ':cost_EUR' => $cost_EUR
));
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

> PDOStatement::execute — Executes a prepared statement
>
> **Usage**: *public bool PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] )*
>
> Here is the example from the documentation:
>
> ```
> <?php
> /* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
> $calories = 150;
> $colour = 'red';
> $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
>     FROM fruit
>     WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
> $sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
> ```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) but I don't understand why I don't need to execute $sql?

Comment: Ahh.. just realized, do you have a prepare statement? I just stepped out. You need to prepare like in the documentation example

Comment: I updated my answer to include the prepare statement.  This of course assumes $this->_dbi is an instance of the PDO object.

Comment: you don't need to execute SQL because.... the `prepare` method will parse and find out variables to be binded then `execute` will find the matching variables to bind and actually run the query.  you could create a wrapper method to make it all one method if you wanted to.  Does that help to answer your question?